# razor URL actionlink

Tags: razor, routes, actionlink

I am trying to create this URL link:

```
mysite.com/Vote/2/Learn-to-code
```

Where 
area = vote, 
id = 2, 
topicURL = Learn-to-code

In my routing, I have this to handle this URL pattern:

```
context.MapRoute(
               "Topic",
               "Vote/{id}/{topicURL}",
               new { controller = "Topic", action = "TopicAnswers" },
               new[] { "eus.UI.Areas.Vote.Controllers"}
             );
```

But I am having trouble generating the URL link. Here's my attempt:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ViewBag.TopicTitle", "TopicAnswers", new { area = "Vote", controller = "Topic", id = ViewBag.TopicId, topicURL = @ViewBag.TopicURL })
```

First question is: How do I use ViewBag.TopicTitle? If I remove the quotes, it gives red squiggly error. I put the quotes in just so I could run the app to see what URL this generates.

It generates a monster URL.

```
mysite.com/Vote/Topic/TopicAnswers/2?url=Learn-to-code
```

However, the URL actually works. But I would really like to create my short and clean looking URL.

```
mysite.com/Vote/2/Learn-to-code
```

Any tips greatly appreciated, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did this and it works. This is so simple to read and understand.

```
<a href="/Vote/@ViewBag.TopicId/@ViewBag.TopicURL">@ViewBag.TopicTitle</a>
```

Is there any good reason why I should attempt to use @Html.ActionLink(...). That just feels like spaghetti.

For starters, why do they place the parameters ("text", action, controller) in this order? That is such a twisty path. This is far more natural to think of: 
(controller, action, "text") ... is it not?